# tracing calls to copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public :
    Student() { };
    Student(const Student& s) { cout << "COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED\n";}
};

Student f(Student u)
{
    Student v(u);
    Student w = v;
    return w;
}

main()
{
    Student x;
    Student y = f(f(x));
}
```

According to me there should be 8 calls as each function call calls the copy constructor 4 times.

1) copying x to parameter u
2) copying u to v
3) copying v to w
4 ) returning w

Please help me. I am having lots of difficulty in understanding these concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each function call will call the copy constructor 3 times. This is due to **Return Value Optimization (RVO)**. The first call will call the copy constructor 3 times and the second call will call the constructor 2 times only because the return value of the first is being passed on to the second.

The first call the copy constructor is called at:

```
1) Copying x to u
2) Copying u to v
3) Copying v to w
```

The second time the copy constructor is called at:

```
1) Copying u to v
2) Copying v to w
```

At other places, optimization is done by the compiler.

Comment: When I compiled using gcc compiler there were 7 calls. Also I don't understand why there would be know call when returning.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the places where you'd expect copy constructors to get called don't really get called due to [return value optimization (RVO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

If I compile your code using:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11
```

I get the following output:

```
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
```

If I compile your code using:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11  -fno-elide-constructors
```

I get the following output.

```
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
```

Comment: Why there are 5 in the first one and 9 in the second. Could you please explain ?

Comment: @RishabhKumar, the explanation by Nivetha [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30690214/434551) explains it.

Comment: -fno-elide-constructors specifies to the compiler not to create temporaries. Hence in the second case, there are 9 calls. In the first case, with optimization, there are only 5 calls as i explained in my answer.

Comment: Okay I understand your explations but can you also make it clear when could it possibly have 7 calls.

Comment: @RishabhKumar, No, I can't explain why you have 7 calls. It doesn't make sense to me.